# How to restrict a textbox without entering any single quotes?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to restrict sinqle qoute in text box through keypress event.

```
private void PAddress_Text_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyChar==''')
        {
            e.Handled=true;
        }
    }
```

I tried with above code. 
But I am getting Empty character literal error in the IDE(Visual Studio IDE).

Comment: Why do you want to restrict a single quote? Is it SQL-driven, per chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the single quote:

```
private void PAddress_Text_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyChar=='\'')
        {
            e.Handled=true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape it. Use this:

```
if (e.KeyChar == '\'')
```